# SqlParameter object: Why do I need to mess with all the options?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I call a stored procedure from .NET code, I could you this to specify a param value:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", myvalue1);
```

If I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure, is there ever a need to specify other optional SqlParameter property values such as Length, datatype, precision, etc, when I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure?

When *is* it necesary?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the extra parameters when you are dealing with a datatype that requires them.

For example - you can't use the simple overload with floating point data types, as you must specify the precision and scale as defined on the server.

When not specifying them on a type that requires them, you will get a `SqlException` with a descriptive message to this effect.

In such cases, you can't use `AddWithValue`, but need to use `Add` passing in a `SqlParameter` object.